# can't find module - react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I just want to link the files but it's not working. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Could you please let me know. This is my first day using react. So, please forgive. I am following this gatsby tutorial.

gatsbyjs.com/docs/tutorial/part-2/

js

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'gatsby'

const IndexPage = () => {
  return (
    <main>
      <title>Home Page</title>
      <h1>Welcome to my Gatsby site!</h1>
      <Link to="/about">About</Link>
      <p>I'm making this by following the Gatsby Tutorial.</p>
    </main>
  )
}

export default IndexPage
```

js second page

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'gatsby'
const AboutPage = () => {
  return (
    <main>
      <title>About Me</title>
      <h1>About Me</h1>
      <Link to="/">Back to Home</Link>
      <p>Hi there! I'm the proud creator of this site, which I built with Gatsby.</p>
    </main>
  )
}
export default AboutPage
```

Comment: Did you do a `yarn install` (or npm)?

Comment: Import React from 'react'; ,no???

Comment: You should include your directory structure. For example is each component inside `src/pages`?

Answer (score 1):

Try `import React from 'react'` instead